# Find the analytical formula of the function (picture included)

Tags: graphing-functions, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

So we're practicing Laplace transforms and I think I came across a rather unorthodox question. The question is:

Find the analytical formula of the function:

[image: Graph]

**NOTE** $h(t)$ is the *Heaviside* function.

a) $h(t) - h(t-1)$

b) $th(t) - th(t-1)$

c) $th(t) - th(t+1)$

d) $th(t) + th(t-1)$

So, the correct answer in my workbook is $b) th(t) - th(t-1)$

However, I don't understand how I'm supposed to read the equation by looking at the photo. If the term $h(t-1)$ denotes a translation to the right (by one), why is that term negative? Why couldn't it be $ th(t) + th(t-1)$?

Thanks for taking the time to read my question!

Comment: Strictly as a psychological matter, (b) is the obvious choice. Note that (a) is the only one without a $t$ multiplier, (c) is the only one that does $t+1$ instead of $t-1$ in the second function, and (d) is the only one to add the functions instead of subtract. These hint strongly that the unique thing about (b) will be it is the only one that is right.  That doesn't show anything mathematically, but if I were in a hurry and was willing to take a chance without checking, that is definitely the chance I would take.

Answer (score 3):

You are not supposed to read the equation from the photo. But you are supposed to be able tell which of those four possibilities produces this function.

- (a) is easily dismissed. $a\left(\frac 12\right) = 1$ not $\frac 12$ as in the graph.
- (d) is also easily dismissed. $d(2) = 2h(2) + 2h(1) = 4$, not $0$.
- (c) needs just a little more inspection, but not much: $c\left(-\frac 12\right) = -\frac 12\left(h\left(-\frac 12\right) - h\left(\frac 12\right)\right) = \frac 12$, not $0$.

So the answer must be (b). But we can show that (b) does indeed produce this graph:

- If $t < 0$, then so is $t-1$, so both $h(t)$ and $h(t-1)$ are $0$. Therefore $b(t) = 0$.
- If $0 < t < 1$, then $t-1 < 0$, so $h(t) = 1, h(t-1) = 0$ and $b(t) = t$, which matches the photo.
- if $1 < t$, then both $t, t-1 > 0$, so $h(t) = h(t-1) = 1$, and $b(t) = t(1-1) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Let's call the signal x(.) as defined by Heaviside function h(.).
 Only (b) is correct.
```

(a) x(.)is a signal of a step function instead of ramp.  Hence it is incorrect.

(b) x(.) is correct. it is a ramp t starting with amplitude 0 at t=0 and ending
with amplitude 1 at t=1.

```
  During the interval [0 1], the signal is active, x(x) ramp up from 0 to 1.  
  At t=1, the signal becomes inactive or we say it is switched off.  
  x(t)=0 when t>=1.
```

(c) x(.) is a signal active during the interval [-1 0] with $negative$ ramp
starting from amplitude 0 when t=-1 and reaching amplitude -1 when t=0.
Incorrect.

(d) x(.) is a ramp starting at t=-1 and double its ramp at t = 0 and continue
$forever$.

```
 Compared with (b), not only it is not ending at t= 0, it ramps at doubling 
 rate 2t and continue forever.
 Incorrect.
```

Comment: For (a): one should say that it's the signal of a "rect" function.